# How to get a substring of a path name with Ansible?

Tags: ansible

I want to install tomcat via ansible on a **windows server**, I check if there is alreay a java installation and get the path to java.exe. Which is:

```
"path": "D:\\Products\\abcd\\java\\jdk1.8.0_51\\bin\\java.exe"
```

I need to set JAVA_HOME in a config var for tomcat, how can I get the needed part -> `D:\\Products\\abcd\\java\\jdk1.8.0_51` from the path? I can not get JAVA_HOME from the remote server since there are various installations.

```
TASK [tomcat : debug] 
ok: [v-sax-769-e-a.develop.ebiz.grp] => {
    "file_info_java.files[0]": {
        "attributes": "Archive",
        "checksum": "8c2c2f3d687fe99d9a724514f09f53bcb989a1e0",
        "creationtime": 1511365795.4331064,
        "extension": ".exe",
        "filename": "java.exe",
        "isarchive": true,
        "isdir": false,
        "ishidden": false,
        "islnk": false,
        "isreadonly": false,
        "isshared": false,
        "lastaccesstime": 1511365795.4331064,
        "lastwritetime": 1438168336,
        "owner": "BUILTIN\\Administrators",
        "path": "D:\\Products\\CPeRef\\java\\jdk1.8.0_51\\bin\\java.exe",
        "size": 206400
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To extract a path given in Windows format, use [`win_dirname` filter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_filters.html#id7):

```
vars:
  path: "D:\\Products\\abcd\\java\\jdk1.8.0_51\\bin\\java.exe"
tasks:
  - debug:
      msg: "{{ path | win_dirname }}"
```

Result:

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "D:\\Products\\abcd\\java\\jdk1.8.0_51\\bin"
}
```

---

But, as you seemingly want to get rid of `bin`-part, you need to decide on a method. Either way, you can do it with a regex filter:

- remove the last element from the path:

  ```
  {{ path | win_dirname | regex_replace('\\\\(?:(?!\\\\).)*$', '') }}
  ```
- remove the last `\\bin` from the path:

  ```
  {{ path | win_dirname | regex_replace('\\\\bin$', '') }}
  ```
- remove the fixed part without using `win_dirname` at all:

  ```
  {{ path | regex_replace('\\\\bin\\\\java.exe$', '') }}
  ```

Comment: Thanks, is there a method to assing the extracted path to a variable instead of doing this in a debug statement?

Comment: Yes: use it in a variable assignment instead of a debug statement.

Comment: I have done it with set_facts:- set_fact: some_variable={{ file_info_java.files[0].path | win_dirname | regex_replace('\\\\bin', '') }}
but isn't there a better way than to spoil the facts?

Comment: so set_facts is working, but isn't there a different method to assign variables I am almost sure but I don't find it in the docs

Comment: Just put this Jinja2 template wherever you need to use it. I don't understand your concerns.